# H2 create fresh new database from existing database

Tags: h2

I want to create a new database, without any data, from an existing db schema with it's constraints, sequences, triggers etc.

At the moment, I export the existing database with [`SCRIPT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) `NODATA TO 'foo'`

The problem with this solution is that sequences are not reinitialized. Is there a way to do it or do I just have to edit the created script file?

Comment: You could remove all "insert" statements?

Comment: You mean the insert statements that are in 'foo' ? There are no insert statements since I used the option NODATA

Comment: You would need to remove the "nodata" option.

Comment: Then I would need to edit the script to remove the insert statements... Might be a little easier using grep, but I just edited the sequences eventually. Thanks for your help